# Simplifying input of strings with strsplit()

Tags: r

How can I reproduce this:

```
x <- strsplit('
Statement A
Statement B
Statement C
', '\n')[[1]][-1]
```

With a format that looks like this:

```
x <- someFunction(
Statement A
Statement B
Statement C
)
```

I'm getting really tired of copying and pasting `', '\n')[[1]][-1]`. The overall goal here is to avoid having to type "double quotes" around each string.

Comment: Can't you store it in external text file and use `readLines`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, but because these are "functions within functions" it doesn't work so nicely. I need it to work independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is use `scan()`:

```
x <- scan(what="character",sep="\n")
Statement A
Statement B
Statement C

x
[1] "Statement A" "Statement B" "Statement C"
```

Though that simply replaces one thing to copy paste with another. If you don't want that, why not just make a wrapper function that does exactly what you say above?

```
spl <- function(x)
{
foo <- unlist(strsplit(x,'\n'))
foo[foo!=""]
}

spl('
Statement A
Statement B
Statement C
')
[1] "Statement A" "Statement B" "Statement C"
```

EDIT:
If you really want to avoid the ' signs, then I think a short named wrapper function around the `scan()` statement is your best bet:

```
foo <- function(x)scan(what="character",sep="\n")

x <- foo()
Statement A
Statement B
Statement C
```

You could cook something up with a function using the `...` sign, and `match.call()` to get it as characer, but when you use spaces that does not work anymore (as they are invalid object names, and you need the ` sign.

Comment: The second one is close, but you still have to type ' and ') (I have to do this hundreds of times)

Answer (score 2):

Does `unlist` do what you want?

```
someFunction <- function(txt) {
  unlist(strsplit(txt, "\n"))
}

#Dummy data
txt <- "Statement A
Statement B
Statement C"

> z <- someFunction(txt)
> all.equal(x,z)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Still have to type "" for this one. But it looks better than what I had before.